# Inserting Component modules in Dagger 2 using Gradle

Tags: gradle, dagger-2, dagger, annotation-processing

### What we have:

A Java/Gradle project with Dagger 2.
And some Component interface :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { 
        ConcreteModule1.class, 
        ConcreteModule2.class,
        ConcreteModule3.class})
public interface CoolComponent
{
    CoolObject getCoolObject();
}
```

### What we want:

Each of our customers gets a slightly different products, so we made a gradle task for each individual jar, that we release. It would be great if we were able to tell our Component, which Modules are used **from within the gradle task**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = @PutListOfConcreteModulesHere )
public interface CoolComponent
{
    CoolObject getCoolObject();
}
```

Each task looks somewhat like this (very simplified):

```
task buildABC{

group 'software-releases'
description 'build for customer ABC'

dependsOn 'generateDaggerClasses'   // custom task btw
dependsOn 'build'
tasks.findByName('build').mustRunAfter 'generateDaggerClasses'    
}
```

### Back to the Question

Can Gradle insert concrete modules into `CoolComponent` ( where I put `@PutListOfConcreteModulesHere`  ), before running `generateDaggerClasses` ?

---

We are fairly new to Dagger 2 and I must admit, that our knowledge of Gradle is rather shallow, so we're grateful for constructive and explained answers. Still learning basics here.